# vertices' attributes are not written to file when using igraph package in R

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I am using igraph in R to calculate some network centrality measures. Once the measures are ready, I want to write the graph into a file (say Pajek format)

```
V(net)$deg_net <- degree(net, loops = F)
V(net)$cls_net <- closeness(net)
```

now the network "net" looks like this"

```
>net
IGRAPH UNW 80000 240000 --
+ attr: name (v/c), deg_net (v/n), cls_net (v/n), weight (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
.
.
.
```

When I use

```
write.graph(net, "team_measures.txt", "pajek")
```

the final text file doesn't seem to include any information about the vertices, including their attributes (degree and closeness measures). It just is:

*Vertices 80000

*Edges

1 1555 1

1 6153 1

1 785 1

and so on. Am I doing something wrong?

I should also mention that "net" is a one-mode projection of a bipartite network.

Comment: [gephi.org](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/pajek-net-format/) says `Attributes support is however missing, only the network topology can be represented with a Pajek File.`

Comment: is there anyway I can export vertices and their attributes? I need them for my analysis.

Comment: A different page at [gephi](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/) describes the properties of different file formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! This is how I did it (far from optimal way!):

```
V(net)$deg_net <- degree(net, loops = F)
V(net)$cls_net <- closeness(net)
options(max.print=1000000)
sink("degree.txt")
V(net)$deg_net
sink()
sink("closeness.txt")
V(net)$cls_net
sink()
```

Then took the text files and did some editing in excel and saved the files as csv. Please let me know if you can think of a better way. 
Thank you,